# How to start session whether user is logged in via facebook connect or my own form?

Tags: php, forms, facebook, authentication

I provide two login/reg options: facebook connect and my own login/reg form.

I want to take users to the same page after they have logged in whether they use fb connect or my form.

I can make it work for one OR the other.  So if user logs in through fb connect, they go to a page with this, for example:

```
//$_SESSION['user'] seems to be the facebook session. 
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) { 
   echo "sorry"; 
} else { 
   include"myconfig.php";
   $email = GetSQLValueString($_SESSION['user'], "text");
   //The email from fb has already been inserted into my mysql users table...
   $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = %s",$email);
   $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
   echo($row['user_name']);
   echo "<b>   EMAIL : </b>" . $row['user_email'];
}
```

And that all works fine.  But if the user has logged in with my form, how do I set another session along with the fb one?  I don't even know where to start because I cannot get a handle on the logic.  I want to say:  "If the user has logged in through fb, then show the stuff from the row in the users table that contains his email , or if he has logged in through my form, then also show that stuff."  Should I just have two versions of every page, one for fb users and another for my form users?

I could find this question nowhere else, so I assume the solution is so easy that I am the only one too stupid to get it.

Comment: Was my answer helpful at all?  I'm not sure where this question stands now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how you are letting them log into facebook, but personally, I use:

```
if ($fbinfo['facebook_app_id']) {
    // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $fbinfo['facebook_app_id'],
        'secret' => $fbinfo['facebook_app_secret'],
    ));

    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    // Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
    if ($user) {
        $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

        if (!$_SESSION['extened_fb_token']) {
            // ask for the extended token and get it from session ...
            $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
            $access_token = $_SESSION["fb_".FB_APP_ID."_access_token"];
            // now set it into the facebook object ....
            $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
            // now our fb object will use the new token as usual ...
            setCompanyFacebookExtendedToken($facebook->getAccessToken());
        }

        //print_r($_SESSION);
        //print_r(facebookGetUserPages($user));
        //echo $_SESSION['extened_fb_token'];
    } else {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'manage_pages,publish_stream'));
    }
}
```

With this, I have already made a query to the database to find out what the app key is (because I have "companies" in my db, and each one can have their own fb app for their users).  Using their information, I use the facebook api to find out if they are logged in or not.  If they are not, I generate the login url.  Once they log in, `$user` contains their facebook user ID which could then be queried in my own database to find out which user it actually is.  Inside the if statement where `$user` is true, I could make a db call that pulled that users email address and assigned it to my own `$_SESSION['user']` variable.  So for you, it might look like:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    //Handle your post normally here
}else{
    if ($fbinfo['facebook_app_id']) {
        // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => $fbinfo['facebook_app_id'],
            'secret' => $fbinfo['facebook_app_secret'],
        ));

        // Get User ID
        $user = $facebook->getUser();

        // Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
        if ($user) {
            $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

            //This is just getting an extended token that is good for 60 days
            if (!$_SESSION['extened_fb_token']) {
                // ask for the extended token and get it from session ...
                $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
                $access_token = $_SESSION["fb_".FB_APP_ID."_access_token"];
                // now set it into the facebook object ....
                $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
                // now our fb object will use the new token as usual ...
                setCompanyFacebookExtendedToken($facebook->getAccessToken());
            }

            include"myconfig.php";

            //The email from fb has already been inserted into my mysql users table...
            $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE fb_id = %s",$user);
            $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
            echo($row['user_name']);
            echo "<b>   EMAIL : </b>" . $row['user_email'];
                $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_email'];
        } else {
            $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'manage_pages,publish_stream'));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Sorry, guess this didn't fully answer your question.  You can really either rename your own user session variable, or once they log in with facebook, get the data you need from facebook then overwrite their session variable (essentially logging them out of facebook, but you've already got the data you need from facebook anyway).  Really, I think that it's the token that is all you need to have them logged into facebook, though it will probably cause the user session variable to be overwritten any time the page loads, so you'd need to remove the facebook sessions altogether, or just rename your session variables.

(I'm still new to facebook api, so I hope that this makes sense.)

Comment: Thank you James.  That is indeed how I get users logged in through fb, and I think you are right that the fb sessions would have to be removed.  I have noticed some sites send a confirmation to the user and force him to log in anew after registering through fb, and I guess the goal there is to create a whole new session without fb.  But rather than try to start a new session, I have decided to have one of each page for fb users and one for myform users.  It is a small site, and most of the content will be the same, so any changes can be copy/paste from myform page to fb page.